# What is $('blah')?

Tags: angularjs

Sorry for the vague description but I don't know the terminology for a whatever a $() represents.

I am looking through some Angular code and see the following syntax which I am unable to decipher.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
 $('[role="alert"]').attr('role', null);
```

I have my guesses as to what this does, but I would love for someone to give me a clear answer.

Thanks

Comment: It is jQuery! `$` is a equivalent to `jQuery` which is a function. You are allowed to use `$` as a variable name!

Comment: to add on to what @callum said, you can consider $() to be a super-charged-ultra-fancy version of document.getElementById() that also washes your dishes, folds your laundry, walks your dog, AND helps out with a ton of stuff related to web pages and JS.

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/dollar-object-vs-function/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `$` alias for jQuery. `$()` is function which can select DOM element(includes all HTML elements) on web page. For example `$('#container')` selects HTML element whose id  is equal to 'container'. You can look into other ways to select html element at [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp).

You can check other usages of `$()` or `jQuery()` at [link](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/).

In your code `$('[role="alert"]')` selects all html elements with attribute role equal to 'alert'. This function returns a jquery object.

.attr() is a jquery function which sets the value of attribute of selected html element. For example, say we have a element `<div id='test1'></div>`. And we have a code like `$('#test1').attr('disabled', 'disabled')`. It would change element to `<div id='test1' disabled='disabled'></div>`

So, line

```
$('[role="alert"]').attr('role', null);
```

would search for all html element with attribute `role = 'alert'` and set their role attribute to null i.e. remove it.

```
<div id='test1' role='alert'></div>
```

would become

```
<div id='test1'></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that complete description.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> $('[role="alert"]').attr('role', null);

Sets the attribute value of 'role' to null

$() is of jquery which will select an element in the DOM.

Also see for reference: https://api.jquery.com/

Comment: that's what it does. OP is asking what $() **IS**.